# plt.figure() doesnt work with multiprocessing on macOS

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, multiprocessing

plt.figure() doesn't seem to work when using multiprocessing and on a macOS (sierra).  Using single thread works ok though.  I am using version 2.0.2 of matplotlib.

When on windows 7, multiprocessing does work, though i had version 1.5.1 matplotlib.

For simplicity, use the code below for testing.  It stops at plt.figure() with no errors or warnings.  Not sure why.

```
def plot(log_name,num):
    numbers = [ random.randint(1,20) for _ in range(10) ]
    fig = plt.figure()                      ## crashes here, with no error
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(numbers ,numbers ,label="test1")
    ax.plot(numbers , numbers , label="test2")
    ax.set_xlabel('Test1')
    ax.set_ylabel('Test2')
    ax.legend()
    fig.savefig("figures/"+str(num)+".png")
    plt.close(fig)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    ## Single process works.  A figure is generated
    #plot("1",1)

    ## Multiprocesses doesnt work.  No figures will be generated
    p1 = Process(target=plot,args=("1",1))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=plot, args=("2", 2))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Does anybody know a work around to this?